# Finding the most repeated element in an array of objects in С#?

Tags: c#, file-io, containers

**My task:**
"The text file U16.txt contains information about commercials. The line includes the following information: advertised product, product group, video duration, video format in pixels (width, height). Create a Clip class to store data about a single clip. Create a Clips container class to hold all the info about commercials. Write a program to print the original commercial data in a tabular format.

Find the most popular product groups (repeating most often) for advertised products. If there are several such product groups, find them all and save them in a separate container. Create a container of clips of the specified W x H format (width, height are entered from the keyboard) so that it includes only one clip from a certain group. Sort this container by clip duration and product group. Calculate the total duration of the clips from the newly created container."

**Unable to implement:**
"Find the most popular product groups (repeating most often) for advertised products. If there are several such product groups, find them all and save them in a separate container."

**There is whole code:**
**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        const string Clips = "U16.txt";
        const string Cresult = "Result.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Cresult)) 
                File.Delete(Cresult);
            
            Clips clips = new Clips();
            Read(Clips, clips);
            Print("Info about clips", Cresult, clips);

            Clips sortClips = new Clips();
            int k = 0;
            /*string[] names = GetGroupsName(ref k, faculty);
            CreateGroups(names, k, groups, faculty);*/
            clips.Sort();
            Print("\nSort clips info", Cresult, clips);
        }

        static void Read(string file, Clips clips)
        {
            string line;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(';');
                    string product = parts[0];
                    string group = parts[1];
                    string duration = parts[2];
                    string format = parts[3];
                    Clip newClip = new Clip(product, group, duration, format);
                    clips.AddClip(newClip);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Print(string Topic, string fresult, Clips clips)
        {
            string top =
            "------------------------------------------\r\n" +
            "Product   Group     Duration    Format " +
            "\r\n------------------------------------------";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fresult, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Topic);
                writer.WriteLine(top);
                for (int i = 0; i < clips.Get(); i++)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(clips.Get(i).ToString());
                }
                writer.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Clip class file**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Clip
    {
        private string Product, Group, Duration, Format;

        public Clip(string Product, string Group, string Duration, string Format){
            this.Product = Product;
            this.Group = Group;
            this.Duration = Duration;
            this.Format = Format;
        }

        public string getProduct() { return Product; }
        public string getGroup() { return Group; }
        public string getDuration() { return Duration; }
        public string getFormat() { return Format; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string line;

            line = String.Format("{0,-8}  {1,-5}  {2,-2}  {3,3}  ",
                Product, Group, Duration, Format);
            return line;
        }
        public static bool operator >= (Clip g1, Clip g2)
        {
            int v = String.Compare(g1.Group, g2.Group,
            StringComparison.CurrentCulture);

            int p = String.Compare(g1.Duration, g2.Duration,
            StringComparison.CurrentCulture);

            return (p > 0 || (p == 0 && v > 0));
        }

        public static bool operator <= (Clip g1, Clip g2)
        {
            int v = String.Compare(g1.Group, g2.Group,
            StringComparison.CurrentCulture);

            int p = String.Compare(g1.Duration, g2.Duration,
            StringComparison.CurrentCulture);

            return (p < 0 || (p == 0 && v < 0));
        }
    }
}
```

**Clips class-container file**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Clips
    {
        private int n;
        private Clip[] clips;
        const int CMax = 100;

        public Clips()
        {
            n = 0;
            clips = new Clip[CMax];
        }

        public void AddClip(Clip clip)
        {
            if (n < CMax)
                clips[n++] = clip;
        }

        public Clip Get(int index){ return clips[index]; }
        public int Get() { return n; }

        public void Sort() {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                Clip temp = clips[i];
                int index = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                    if (clips[j] <= temp)
                    {
                        temp = clips[j];
                        index = j;
                    }
                clips[index] = clips[i];
                clips[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data txt file**

```
Product1; BGroup; 00:05:55; 1280 x 720
Product2; AGroup; 00:15:25; 1920 x 1080
Product3; BGroup; 00:02:44; 1280 x 720
Product4; BGroup; 00:07:01; 1920 x 1080
Product5; AGroup; 00:05:55; 1920 x 1080
```

On the Internet, I seem to have found an algorithm for finding the most repeated value, but the problem is:

Let's say an array is given int[] arr = { 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 30, 30, 40 };

In the end displays 40 30 40 30 30 40

Well, that is, everything is correct 40 and 30 are the most repetitive, but I don’t need these numbers themselves to be displayed at the end, that is, the output should only have 2 numbers, 40 and 30, and not like this: "40 30 40 30 30 40"

**Algorithm:**

```
// C# program to find the most frequent element
// in an array
using System;
public class GFG
{
    // C# program to find the most frequent element
    // in an array.
    public static void mostFrequent(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        int maxcount = 0;
        int[] ints = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count >= maxcount)
            {
                maxcount = count;
                ints[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ints[i] != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ints[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 30, 30, 40 };
        int n = arr.Length;
        mostFrequent(arr, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: could do something like group by the value, then sort by the count, and take the values with the max counts.

Comment: "Algorithm" ?? - Yeah. It's called "counting". Create a `Dictionary<string, int>` , and then build a histogram. Then you can find the most frequent entries (groups) easily. Are you allowed to use LINQ?

Comment: @Fidor I'm not sure I'd start with a dictionary when `Linq` has a handy `.GroupBy()` method. ;-)
From there it should be easy to find the max count and select any values with the same count as max.

Comment: @Joe_DM This being an obvious homework, using LINQ _may_ be forbidden to OP. As is using proper C# conventions and higher data structures, seemingly.

Comment: Well, not so obvious homework as these kind of things do pop up. Maybe just ask what would Linq do behind the scenes? In this case it would guess that it does something like loop through each object and place them into a shared wrapper, the thing that makes it distinct ends up being a key and the collection of said group is an object within... Sounds suspiciously like a `Dictionary<string, object>` close to what @Fildor suggested. Except that he suggested closer to `Dictionary<string, int>` which is more efficient since you know you only care about keeping count of the occurrences of the key.